# Builder that returns a Value from a File

Tags: python, scons

Is there a way to make a builder which returns a Value instead of a File? Several steps in my build system follow this pattern:

1. Read value from file
2. Generate value based on file, e.g. count how many times the word 'foo' occurs.
3. Generate an `Action` based on this value.

So I might want to have a command like this:

```
source_value = env.SomeBuilder(<value target>, 'input_file.txt')
env.Command('output.txt', source_value,
     'my_function $SOURCE $TARGET')
```

The examples here show how to make a `Value` from a `Value`, but not a `Value` from a `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out `AddMethod()` in chapter 20 "Pseudo-Builders" of the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ). It allows you to call your own method/function where you access the source name, open the file, read and process its contents and then create and return a `Value` node (untested, and from the top of my head):

```
def GetValueFromFile(env, source):
    result = ""
    with open(str(source), "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        # process read content, e.g.
        result = str(content.count("foo"))
    return env.Value(result)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The one thing I'm not sure this addresses is dependency management.  Reading the source file and generating the value can be quite expensive (it's much more complex than just counting, that was a simplified example).  So ideally, if the source file and the target file are both unchanged, I don't want the source file to be re-read.  I get that behaviour with a real builder, is there a way to replicate it and still generate a `Value`?

Comment: In that case I'd pack the parsing and processing of the source file into its own Builder, and let it create an intermediate file (in the simple example above it would contain only the number, let's say, "3"). Then create a Value node from that file's contents with GetValueFromFile...and SCons should pick up the dependencies correctly.